# Convert an integer to time, then query if current time is past that integer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am tasked with designing a shipping system at our facility. Currently we receive the orders from the customer with a truck pickup time in military format as an integer. If a customer has two pickup today at like 6:30 AM and 5:00 PM it'll show two orders with "0630" and "1700" in the int column. I need to first convert that int time to military time, and then do a system date check time to see if that order is past current time. So if it's 7:00 AM, I need the 6:30 AM order to just not show up any longer in the query.

Link to SQL fiddle with schema: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/b52be

I'm not sure how to convert the integer over to a readable time format. Ideally, at least I think, if I could just get it to the current date time format I can just add in a where clause where if it's > getdate() don't show, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand your requirement correctly, then you could convert the `int` value to a `time` as I have done in the `VALUES` clause, and then reference that in the `WHERE`. Note, however, that this will affect the performance of the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(time(0),STUFF(RIGHT('0000' + CONVERT(varchar(4), pickup),4),3,0,':')))) V(pickuptime)
WHERE o.shipdate >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND v.pickuptime > CONVERT(time(0), GETDATE());
```

Working the other way, and converting the current datetime to an `int` (which will likely perform far better):

```
SELECT *
FROM orders o
     CROSS APPLY(VALUES(CONVERT(int,REPLACE(LEFT(CONVERT(varchar(8),CONVERT(time,GETDATE()),109),5),':',''))))V(GD)
WHERE o.shipdate >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())
  AND o.pickup > V.GD;
```

Comment: Hmm, so maybe we could work backwards and convert the getdate() to int to possibly take advantage of indexes?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking that @GeorgeMenoutis

Comment: @Larnu Could you give me a brief run down on the cross apply? I've never seen that before, but I'm also quite the amateur in this field.

Comment: CROSS APPLY is awesome! Check some cool functionalities it provides here: http://bradsruminations.blogspot.com/2011/04/t-sql-tuesday-017-it-slices-it-dices-it.html

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is normally used with table value functions, @DaveHolt. Unlike a `JOIN` it doesn't need an `ON` clause (infact it doesn't support `ON`, as you'd normally use a correlated query). Also, unlike a `JOIN` with a subquery you **can** reference objects outside of the `JOIN`; I find that particular part of it invaluable with thigns like "`TOP 1` joins"). In this case I'm using the `VALUES` clause with an expression that (in the end) converts the value of `pickup` to a `time`, or `GETDATE()` to a integer representation of the current time (depending on which query you are looking at).

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the explanation, I'm marking as solved. You're awesome!

Answer (score 2):

Just add the time to your date:

```
SELECT partnum, DATEADD(mi, pickup%100, DATEADD(hh, pickup/100, CONVERT(DATETIME, shipdate)))
FROM orders
WHERE DATEADD(mi, pickup%100, DATEADD(hh, pickup/100, CONVERT(DATETIME, shipdate))) > GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to store the dates in the `datetime` field, instead of storing them in the `int` field. The reason is, today, you are getting the parameters as military format and tomorrow you might get in different format. That should not decide your storage format. Your storage format should be agnostic of the way it is being queried.

Once you store the dates in standard datetimeformat, the query becomes very simpler. It is not the answer to your question. The answer has already been provided by @Larnu. I am just giving different perspective.

```
DECLARE @pickupDateTimeCutOff DATETIME = GETDATE()
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE  vpickupDateTime < @pickupDateTimeCutOff
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I'm not going to say it can't be done, but I'm not actually generating the orders, this is how we receive it from our customers. It doesn't make sense to me why they do it that way but I have to try and adapt to their requirements.

Comment: @DaveHolt, got it. I understand. thanks for your response.